# LicenseUrl showing up empty when using Get-Package in the VS package manager console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I'm attempting to get the license URLs for each package in a project programmatically using the techniques described [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235082/get-license-information-for-all-used-nuget-packages) and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2015/03/28/download-nuget-package-licenses/).

The output of `Get-Package | Select-Object Id,LicenseUrl` seems like it should work, but LicenseUrl is empty:

```
PM> Get-Package | Select-Object Id,LicenseUrl

Id                                                                                                  LicenseUrl                                                                                         
--                                                                                                  ----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Castle.Core                                                                                                                                                                                            
CommonServiceLocator                                                                                                                                                                                   
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                                                                                                                                                                                   
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor                                                                                                                                                                                 
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi                                                                                                                                                                                
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client                                                                                                                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core                                                                                                                                                                           
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost                                                                                                                                                                        
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages                                                                                                                                                                              
Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache                                                                                                                                                                         
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
```

Is there something I'm missing?  Has the schema of these package objects changed?

Answer (score 1):

Your PowerShell script works fine in Visual Studio 2013.

I am guessing you are using Visual Studio 2015.

In Visual Studio 2015 the package object returned is not the same as it is in NuGet v2 and various properties and methods are no longer available. If you run the following powershell command you can see the properties that are available in NuGet 3.

```
Get-Package | Get-Member
```

Just looking at the properties available in NuGet 3 we have:

```
AllVersions
AsyncLazyVersions
Id
ProjectName
Version
Versions
```

So there is no LicenseUrl available in NuGet 3.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015...is it really no longer accessible at all?  It does look that way from Get-Member.

Comment: Yes, it is no longer accessible. NuGet 3 returns a different object back to represent the package. It is a PowerShellPackage class which has a limited set of properties. Might be worth opening an issue on the [NuGet 3 GitHub repository](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues) to see if they plan to support other properties or if it is gone forever.

Answer (score 1):

The **LicenseUrl** is back in Visual Studio **2015 Update 2**.
[image]

If you use Visual Sutio **2015 Update 1** with Nuget Package Manager 3.3.0, the **LicenseUrl** property is unavailable, but there is still a way to get license URLs. This script works for me:

```
PM> Get-Package | % { $pkg = $_.Id ; Write-Host $_.ProjectName "-" $pkg;
        $url = Open-PackagePage $pkg -License -WhatIf -PassThru; 
        Write-Host "License URL: " $url }
```

Here's the reference for Open-PackagePage cmdlet parameters: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference

```
-License
    Indicates the cmdlet should open the LicenseUrl of the specified package. If neither LicenseUrl nor ReportAbuseUrl 
    is set, the cmdlet will open the Proje
    ctUrl by default.

-PassThru
    If specified, the cmdlet will return the value of the requested URL.
```

The help page warns that this command will be deprecated after NuGet 3.0 RTM. The script displays warning about deprecated command (highlighted below) but it still works.

[image]